# Dismissing ViewController creates camera lag

Tags: ios, swift

My main View controller is a camera view, and if i perform a segue to go to another screen, after i dismiss it, last "frame" of the camera view is shown for half a second before showing the current camera "view".
Do i need to present the second view in another way?

Calling the initial segue:

```
floatyButton.addItem("About", icon: UIImage.init(named: "aboutIcon")) {(item) in
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "aboutPage", sender: Any?.self)
}
```

On the close button for the second view i only use:

```
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am guessing that in some way i need to start loading first ViewController even before second one is dissmised, but not sure how?

Here is the video capture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pv3nypr7rnufhxc/IMG_0565.TRIM.mov?dl=0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the native Camera app, you'll see a similar behavior. Try tapping the photos button on the bottom left to show your photo album, and then hit the back button. You'll see that Apple temporarily shows a visual blur over the camera layer so that you don't see the last captured frame.

You'll need to do some sort of manipulation of the `AVVideoCapturePreviewLayer` right before your first view controller's view is removed from the screen -- for example, the apple way which looks like they take a snapshot of the view, put a blur over it, and then remove the blur once the previewlayer is ready when it is presented again.

Comment: That's exactly right! Just checked the camera app and i am guessing that is the best way to solve it. But can i do that in viewWillAppear as well?

Comment: I would do the adding of the blurred snapshot in `viewWillDisappear`, and then in your `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` add some logic to check if the snapshot is present, and remove if it from it's superView if it is.

Answer (score 1):

put the performSegue inside completion like this below :

```
 dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegueID", sender: nil)

       })
```

Comment: I created a segue to go back to initial screen but same outcome. It does go back but screen shows last frame again. :/
Here is the video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pv3nypr7rnufhxc/IMG_0565.TRIM.mov?dl=0

Comment: Added the code i use for initial segue, but @Daniel pointed out the main issue. It seems its a native "problem."

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not on the segue or dismiss, its on your main... can you show your lifecycle methods of your main ?

Comment: Its too long to post in the comments, but its regular ARWorldTracking configuration stuff. However, it seems that is the way camera works when performing a segue as @Daniel pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply hide the View with Camera preview and stop the Camera.
But not forget to restore it.

```
/*
 `cameraPreview` is the View where Camera preview is showing
 `camera` is type of my own class for managing iOS Camera
 */

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    cameraPreview.isHidden = true
    camera?.stopRunning()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    cameraPreview.isHidden = false
    camera?.startRunning()
}
```